# Limited space and Full SMS memory

Tags: sms, insufficient-memory

I am getting a message that the internal memory space is full. I checked that I have 15MB intenral memory left and 50MB on my SD card.

I also get a message that the SMS memory is full. I deleted some messages but this message doesn't seem to leave!

All these happened when I safely removed the SD card.

What can I do to remove these messages, which I don't believe they are for real. Something nasty must be going on here. Not to mention that before I removed the card the internal memory was about 30MB.

I tried to erese the cache by using `memory wipe` aplication but nothing really happened.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I tried to move some applications to the SD card through the `Application Manager` but the option `move to SD` cannot be pushed, although there is some space in the sd card(~50MB). I tried to move on application with 1MB size in my ~50MB free space SD card...

Does this imply a problem?

Comment: As you've correctly tagged your question, did you check the [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info)? Have you followed any of its first-aid hints? As to the limits: the error mostly gets triggered when space drops below 25 MB. And the SDCard does not matter here -- only device-internal storage ("phone memory"). So please check with the mentioned wiki, then update your question with details where you got stuck (if so) -- or answer your question when solved. Thanks!

Comment: @Izzy: Thank you very much for your comment and advice! I have already done what's described in your link, but there is something that it's really weird... I'll edit my question in order to provide more information.

Comment: I see, thanks for the update. To the problem you've run into, you will want to read the [app2sd tag wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info) -- not all apps are movable (e.g. not when they provide a service or widgets).

Comment: @Izzy: That's the weird part...They are not offering a widget or providing a service...Some of them are `LHSee`,`BarTender`,`Army Fitness`,`Funny Facts Free`,`Fact File`,`Tourist Language`...

Comment: That might be. It still leaves the part that the dev must explicitly mark it to be movable (rather, he must define the target storage). Quting the [API doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html): *To allow the system to install your application on the external storage, modify your manifest file to include the android:installLocation attribute in the <manifest> element, with a value of either "preferExternal" or "auto".* You could try asking the devs to do so (or why not).

Comment: @Izzy: This is nice information! How to edit `<manifest>`? Shall I connect my phone to a PC and try to change(and locate the file itslef) its attribution through any editor?

Comment: No, not you -- the dev must do that. That's nothing the end user should touch. The dev might have some good reason for this decision. I strongly recommend to contact him first. Plus, modifying `.apk` files that way is a little beyond the scope of our site (the `Manifest` is compiled, so you would need to reverse-engineer and rebuild). // PS: the comments already grew a little long (this is not a forum ;) Maybe I sum up from above comments to make an answer, and you pick issues still left open to make new questions out of them? One question per post is our custom here :)